# MaterialTabs Library - Sliding Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, material-design

I am using @NeoKree MaterialTabs in my application, however it lacks SlidingTab support like Official SlidingTabs & PagerSlidingTabStrip Library. Does anyone know how to implement SlidingTabs into this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same example that you can see in googleio14.

It uses a `SlidingTabLayout` which works with a `ViewPager`.

[Here you can find the example](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) (it is in your sdk example)

Here you can find the Google io14 example:

- [Layout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/activity_my_schedule_narrow.xml)
- [Java](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java)